# can multiple smartimages be added as different table in same dialog in cq5

Tags: jsp, adobe, aem

I am trying to add 5 smart images in 5 different tabs . the xtype is html5smartimage.

I am rendering in jsp using the file reference .

i.e.

```
<img src="<%=properties.get("fileReference1")%> //different reference for different smartimages
```

I tried using Image component

```
Image image = new Image(resource, "firstimage");

image.setSelector(".img");

String text = properties.get("text", "TEXT NA");

String path = currentStyle.get("path", "PATH NA");
%>
<h2><%= path %></h2>
<%= text %>
<%
image.draw(out);
%>
```

but it didnt work.

The first approach worked but when i try to edit again the image disappears and the crop is disabled. can anyone let me know what to do?

dialog.xml:

Comment: could you show your dialog.xml ?

Comment: @santiagozky have edited and added dialog.xml

Answer (score 1):

The property names for the smartimage widget can't be changed and must be fileReference, fileName, imageCrop, imageMap, etc. due to how the image servlet works.  In order to have multiple smartimage widgets on a single dialog, you need to store the image data as a child node under the resource and be sure to have it be a sling:resourceType of a component that extends parbase.  The sample configuration below is an example of how you can support multiple smart image widgets.  After your dialog is storing the information in the correct place, you can do resource.getChild("image1").adaptTo(Image.class) and resource.getChild("image2").adaptTo(Image.class) to get the image objects for your different images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
          title="Multiple Smart Images"
          xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Image Properties">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <image1ResType
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                        name="./image1/sling:resourceType"
                        value="foundation/components/image"
                        xtype="hidden"/>
                    <image2ResType
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                                    name="./image2/sling:resourceType"
                        value="foundation/components/image"
                        xtype="hidden"/>
                </items>
            </tab1>
            <tab2
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                cropParameter="./image1/imageCrop"
                ddGroups="[media]"
                fileNameParameter="./image1/fileName"
                fileReferenceParameter="./image1/fileReference"
                mapParameter="./image1/imageMap"
                name="./image1/file"
                requestSuffix="/image1.img.png"
                rotateParameter="./image1/imageRotate"
                title="Image 1"
                uploadUrl="/tmp/upload/*"
                xtype="html5smartimage">
            </tab2>
            <tab3
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                cropParameter="./image2/imageCrop"
                ddGroups="[media]"
                fileNameParameter="./image2/fileName"
                fileReferenceParameter="./image2/fileReference"
                mapParameter="./image2/imageMap"
                name="./image2/file"
                requestSuffix="/image2.img.png"
                rotateParameter="./image2/imageRotate"
                title="Image 2"
                uploadUrl="/tmp/upload/*"
                xtype="html5smartimage">
            </tab3>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: Could you also give an example of how to display the images ? I'm trying to figure this out but havent' any success ! Thanks